# plsql. is there way to get column ddl?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, ddl

I use ***dbms_metadata.get_ddl(...)*** to get object ddl but it is not generate ddl for column.
is there way to get column ddl  oracle 12 version?

thanks

Comment: What does "column DDL" mean to you and in what way is the column's DDL not part of the DDL for the object?  An example showing exactly what you are seeing and exactly what you would want to see would be very helpful.

Comment: I have table and column name and I want to get ddl like 'alter table t add c number default 1 not null'

Comment: you should edit the question to express your problem well rather than commenting.

Comment: As @BarbarosÖzhan has explained, you should edit your question to complete the information you are asking, a comment might get lost if there are a lot of comments. Anyway, you aren't going to get an ALTER TABLE with the get_ddl function, that DDL is to modify an object, the get_ddl gives you the DDL for the existing object.

Comment: Why do you want an `alter table` to add the column rather than just the DDL to create the entire table including the column?  The only reason I can think of that you'd want that is if you are trying to generate DDL in order to converge two different objects.  If so, you'd want to use the `dbms_metadata` and `dbms_metadata_diff` packages (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-E9A778A7-2E9D-4240-8707-A52FF65556FE.htm#SUTIL3627).

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem my self.

I created a `PLSQL` function that extract the column data from table creation DDL in current schema/user.

Than rebuilds an `alter table` command.

The function return the required DDL statement to add the specified column.

#### Function code: `get_column_ddl`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_column_ddl(tableName IN VARCHAR2, columnName IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    outStr VARCHAR2(3333) := 'undefined';
BEGIN
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'STORAGE', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'TABLESPACE', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'CONSTRAINTS', true);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'REF_CONSTRAINTS', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'OID', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SIZE_BYTE_KEYWORD', false);

    -- Introduced collation in Oracle RDBMS 18.c, comment following line in earlier database
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'COLLATION_CLAUSE', 'NEVER');
    
    SELECT
        'ALTER TABLE "'||tableName||'" ADD '||regexp_replace(regexp_substr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', tableName), '"'||columnName||'"[^"]*'), '[,)] $','') into outStr 
    FROM dual;
    RETURN outStr;
END get_column_ddl;
/
```

#### `get_column_ddl()`function usage:

```
CREATE TABLE test_1 (
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    description VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT 'Undefined' NOT NULL
);
select get_column_ddl('TEST_1','ID') from dual 
union
select get_column_ddl('TEST_1','DESCRIPTION') from dual;
```

##### `get_column_ddl()` function return:

```
ALTER TABLE "TEST_1" ADD "ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE
ALTER TABLE "TEST_1" ADD "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT 'Undefined' NOT NULL ENABLE
```

Notice the inclusion of `contraints` and `defaults`.

##### `get_column_ddl()` function limitations:

This function will not provide the `collation` parameters, the defaults `collation` will be used (it was developed for Oracle RDBMS 12).

Incorrect/partial answer for **virtual/derived** columns.

Answer (score -1):

I think following query may usefull for you.

```
SELECT *
    FROM ADMIN.DDL_HISTORY_LOG L
 WHERE L.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
             AND L.DDL = 'ALTER'
             AND L.OBJECT_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' --just change table name here
             AND UPPER(L.DDL_SQL) LIKE '%ALTER%TABLE%ADD%'
             AND UPPER(L.DDL_SQL) NOT LIKE '%ADD%CONSTRAINT%'
```

this oracle dictionary is holding all historic DDL statements. so, If you specify your table name, you can get all DDL statements for this table in the past.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).